# How does Set::Scalar universe work?

Tags: perl, set

I have created many sets and I noticed that all share the same universe.

I couldn't figure out how the universes is maintained. Is it one universe shared by all sets in the script (some global variable)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, actually it's a lexical variable in [Set::Scalar::Universe](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Set%3a%3aScalar%3a%3aUniverse):

```
my $UNIVERSE = __PACKAGE__->new;

sub universe {
    my $self = shift;

    return $UNIVERSE;
}
```

Then in [Set::Scalar](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Set%3a%3aScalar) you have:

```
$self->{ universe } = Set::Scalar::Universe->universe;
```

which simply fetches a copy of that one variable (which got initialized when Set::Scalar::Universe was loaded.

The Set::Scalar docs mention in passing that disjoint universes are not yet implemented.